# Detecting an object containing all empty string property values in php or laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-7, laravel-6

I need to detect if an object's (like the below one) all the properties has an empty string as value. How can I achieve this?

```
object(stdClass)#1282 (9) {
["first_name"]=>
string(0) ""
["last_name"]=>
string(0) ""
["company"]=>
string(0) ""
["address_1"]=>
string(0) ""
["address_2"]=>
string(0) ""
["city"]=>
string(0) ""
["state"]=>
string(0) ""
["postcode"]=>
string(0) ""
["country"]=>
string(0) ""
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is all empty strings/`null` these fields can be filtered out easily:

```
(bool) array_filter((array) $object)
```

If it has a single property that isn't a "falsey" value you will get `true`.

**FYI:** This will also filter out other false values though like, `0`,`'0'`, `false`, etc ...

[PHP.net Manual - Function Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) `array_filter`

Comment: no problem brother, your solution is sufficient for my need.

Answer (score 4):

This should only return `true` if all the properties are empty strings.

```php
return collect((array)$obj)->every(function ($value, $key) {
    return trim($value) === '';
    
});
```

And if you are using PHP 7.4 and above this can be even shorter.

```php
return collect((array) $obj)->every(fn ($v) => '' === trim($v));
```

Comment: @lagbox the question also mentioned "has an empty string as value", if one of the properties is not `string` I think your solution may not work. but I do not know his code, if all the properties are guaranteed all strings now and future then your one is obviously easier, do you mind I add you comment code in my answer? I will put you as a reference.

Comment: the problem isn't the `null` or empty string its all the other "falsey" values, so in that regard yes, my answer will also be removing those values, which may or may not be desired

Comment: @lagbox that's ok no worries, your answer is perfect for its use case I think, it will check all the PHP "falsy" values.

Comment: yea mine may not be what they need though, for this ultra specific example it works fine but as mentioned it will filter out all the other "falsey" values as well .... https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: @lagbox yes, true it's really depending on what he needs.